# Getting 404 in java api

Tags: java

'I am getting 404 by hitting following URL:
http://localhost:8080/JavaApp/rest/hello
Project Name: JavaAPP
Jersey version: 2.29.1
Java Class:
Please help me get this fixed.'

Java Class:

```
    @Path("/hello")
    public class Hello {

          @GET
          @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML) 
          public String sayHello() {
          String recources="<? xml version='1.0' ?>" +
          "<hello>Hi, This is hello from XML</hello>"; 
          return recources; 
          }


    /*
     * @GET
     * 
     * @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) public String sayHelloJson() { String
     * recources=null; return recources; }
     * 
     * 
     * @GET
     * 
     * @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) public String sayHelloHtml() { String
     * recources="<h1>Hello form HTML </h1>."; return recources; }
     */
    }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JavaApp</display-name>


     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Java Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.test.api</param-value>
        </init-param>   
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Java Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Path for the method itself also,

```
  @GET
  @Path("/say")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML) 
  public String sayHello() {
     String recources="<? xml version='1.0' ?>" +
       "<hello>Hi, This is hello from XML</hello>"; 
     return recources; 
  }
```

Now try to call http://localhost:8080/JavaApp/rest/hello/say